# Invalid Post Type error when attempting to filter and Bulk Edit posts

Tags: posts, bulk

WP 3.8.1

Posts Categories:

1. News
   1.1 Press Release
   1.2 etc.
2. Blog
   2.1 Technology
   2.2 Around The World
   2.3  Eetc.

"Invalid Post Type" example:

Posts => Filter by "Press Release" + checkmark ALL + Edit + Apply + I change the author name + Apply:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=Array
```

I basically want to change all Press Release author names. That's it. But I keep getting "Invalid Post Type" error.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? What theme?

Comment: Custom theme with a handful of functions inside functions.php. Currently debugging with all plugins disabled. Bulk Edit works fine with Twenty Fourteen theme. Nothing special in my custom theme--but is there a *gotcha* I should be aware of? Is there a known limitation? Thanks

Comment: Something is using an `array` as if it were a string. I have a hard time believing that Core code is doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for me. A function from my functions.php file was in conflict with my filter admin.

I had to find where was my error, for that I just cut and paste my function one by one and test again and gain till I found my conflict function.

In my case I had to put my function in a conditional tag:

```
if(!is_admin()){

  //Your conflict function

}
```

So Your function will be executed only on the theme and not in your admin.